# How can I call all "p" items from a return in a BS4 function?

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, return

I want to create a function using BS4 that returns all the "p" items from the website, then use it in a second function. The code below successfully prints out all the 'p' items from the website

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_chinese():
    
    url = "https://www.ted.com/talks/lawrence_lessig_we_the_people_and_the_republic_we_must_reclaim/transcript?language=zh-cn"
    content = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs(content.text, 'html.parser')

    mydivs = soup.find_all("p")
    for p in mydivs:
        print( (p.getText()))

get_chinese()
```

However, when I try and use "return" as below, then print when calling the function, only the first "p" block is returned.

```
def get_chinese():
    
    url = "https://www.ted.com/talks/lawrence_lessig_we_the_people_and_the_republic_we_must_reclaim/transcript?language=zh-cn"
    content = requests.get(url)

    soup = bs(content.text, 'html.parser')

    mydivs = soup.find_all("p")
    for p in mydivs:
        return p.getText() 



print(get_chinese())
```

What do I need to do to call all the "p" blocks via the "return" in the "get_chinese()" function?
FYI, the idea is to later write both the Chinese and English to a text file with the code below. this last code works fine, but only the first "p" items are written to file as something is happening in the "return"

```
def create_table():
    chinese = get_chinese()
    english = get_english()
    with open('ted.txt', "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(english)
        output_file.write(chinese)
```

Comment: The return statement breaks the loop after the first iteration. You could use `yield` instead which will turn the function into a generator.

Answer (score 1):

seems to me that the `return` statement is breaking the loop, maybe can try using list to store the "p" first before returning it?

```
chinese_text = []

for p in mydivs:
    chinese_text.append(p.getText())

return chinese_text
```

or list comprehension works too,

```
return [p.getText() for p in mydivs]
```